# What was the “It Could Be” running joke on House MD?

Tags: house

On *House, MD*, there was a running gag were for every case, someone would suggest that it could be a specific disease but it never was (I can’t remember if it ever turned out to be the case).

I knew it not to long ago, but seem to have completely forgotten it now. I keep wanting to say polio, but that doesn’t seem to be right, and Googling it is not turning up anything because most people don’t bother with the “MD”, so searching for `house "it could be"` or even `house md running joke "could be"` aren’t very helpful.

What was the disease that they always suggest it might be? Bonus points if you know if it ever turned out to be correct.

Comment: Lupis, and it actually did happen in one episode.

Comment: I always thought Sarcoidosis was the failing diagnosis submitted most. I seem to remember a website that tracked the diagnoses of the episode of the previous night. UPDATE: [Polite Dissent](http://www.politedissent.com/house_pd.html)

Comment: UPDATE2: I did a rough search on the website above. Lupus count = 70, Sarcoidosis = 44

Comment: @wbogacz. Hmm, I remember sarcoidosis a lot as well. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @TylerShads, you’re right. I’d say that now that I know which one it was, it would be easier to look up which episode it actually was lupus, but that’s still a challenge since every almost episode mentioned it. `:-/`

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101216/is-there-some-hidden-joke-behind-the-its-never-lupus-running-gag-in-house

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was Lupus, and in one episode it actually was Lupus, which the characters commented on as being surprising.

Doing a google search for `house it's never lupus` gets you tons of hits, including to the [Know your meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/its-not-lupus) page.

Comment: Ah yes, that’s it. I was kind of close with polio, it had an l and p.   `Doing a google search for house it's never lupus gets you tons of hits.`   That requires knowing it’s lupus, plus it’s backwards, I remember it as *it could be* not *it’s never*.

Comment: *"That requires knowing it’s lupus, plus it’s backwards"* - Yeah, but this sentence wasn't ever meant as a *"you should have googled better"*-complaint, but a simple *"look, here's more proof of what I'm saying"*-assurance.