# How realistic is House MD series with respect to medical science?

Tags: realism, house

Since I have been watching [House MD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412142/?ref_=sr_1), all the episodes seem to be a bit unrealistic. Does this series have any close actual relevance to medical science?

The series is about cases that most doctors are unable to solve. So it may just be realistic.

Comment: [Related question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13153/what-was-the-it-could-be-running-joke-on-house-md).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a [website managed by a doctor](http://www.politedissent.com/house_pd.html) which reviews the medicine in House M.D.. The site features in an article on Forbes titled, [The Most (And Least) Medically Accurate Episodes Of 'House, M.D.'](http://www.forbes.com/sites/matthewherper/2012/05/21/the-most-and-least-medically-accurate-episodes-of-house-m-d/).

> **But how realistic was the medicine behind those adrenaline- and vitriol-drenched storylines?** There’s really only one authority on that: Scott Morrison, a physician in O’Fallon, Illinois, (and, previously, in the Air Force) who has reviewed every single episode of House, M.D., on his blog, Polite Dissent. Since sometime during season one he has rated each episode using academic-style A-F letter grades not only on its plot, but on the quality of its medicine. He is as tough on House as House is on other doctors. **“An average House episode may rate a C,” he says, “but that is still miles above any other show out there.”**

So the opinion appears to be that the quality varies from episode to episode. Some are very good while others can be unreliable.

Comment: I would argue that the Morrison is saying the standard is pretty low (high would be an A average), but as low as it is, it's higher than other shows...

Comment: @BenPlont You're right. While the scale runs from A–F, that sentence is ambiguous. Removing.